# Cancel button and standard header in quick action on mobile app

Tags: mobile, quickaction, screen-flow

Suppose I have a quick action of type Flow. This is a screen flow where I embed LWC components. I have to be able to open this quick action through custom button placed in some other LWC, so I use redirect to URL because quick action indeed has its own URL. Code snippet below:

```
this[NavigationMixin.Navigate]({
    type: 'standard__webPage',
    attributes: {
        url: '/lightning/action/quick/Employee__c.QA_FlowTest?recordId=' + this.recordId
                
    }
},
```

This works fine on desktop, modal is being rendered. However, when I click a button in LWC component which does this redirection in Mobile App I can see 'cancel' button doing nothing on the top of the page (see below)
[image]

It is possible to get rid of this Cancel button? Can I remove this header as well? I got stuck on that, I would appreciate any help.

Comment: Can you please provide me more information about CANCEL Button. Is it a quick action standard button?